# how do I take the absolute value of a std_logic_vector? in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I can't figure out how to take the absolute value of two std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

here is an example of the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;        
use ieee.numeric_std.all;       -- for the signed, unsigned types and arithmetic ops
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
...
...
port (  
    X: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
    Y: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
    F: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) 
  );

..
..
..
process(X,Y)
 begin
 F <= abs(X-Y)     --this doesnt work
```

Comment: How would you compute the absolute value of a binary value using pencil and paper? Just duplicate that algorithm in VHDL.

Comment: @JoeHass that's the correct answer if you're learning, or if you have to something not built-in, but using the built-in `abs` on the standard `signed` type will often synthesize to better code in many FPGA and ASIC vendor's synthesizers which special case some built-in math operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ditch the non-standard library includes and use the standard `signed` type which has a built-in `abs` function:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;        
use ieee.numeric_std.all; -- this is the standard package where signed is defined
-- never use non-standard ieee.std_logic_arith and ieee.std_logic_unsigned

...

port (  
  X: in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
  Y: in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); 
  F: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) 
);

...

process(X,Y) is
begin
  F <= std_logic_vector(abs(signed(X)-signed(Y)));
end process;
```

That last line has a lot of [probably needless] converting between `std_logic_vector` and `signed`, so you might prefer this interface instead if it makes sense with the rest of your design:

```
port (  
  X: in  signed(31 downto 0); 
  Y: in  signed(31 downto 0); 
  F: out signed(31 downto 0) 
);
```

Then the last line is just:

```
 F <= abs(X-Y);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response, when I remove ieee.std_logic_unsigned_all; I can no longer add or subtract the logic vectors. but when I turn the logic vectors into signed it compiles :D I have no idea why

Comment: Because adding std_logic_vectors makes no sense. Adding signeds makes sense; adding unsigneds also makes sense; the right answer may depend on the type... VHDL is about saying exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Without conveying type there's no way to distinguish between signed and unsigned with only one of each adding, multiplying and signing operators using std_logic_vector. It's a semiotic distinction overcoming a VHDL limitation not a hardware distinction. Also (signed(X)-signed(Y)) conveys the same information to VHDL, treating these std_logic_vector signals as signed. Strong types also sometimes prevents erroneous design specification of operations between signed and unsigned integer representations of std_ulogic arrays. We may get pedantic objections to something allowed in VHDL, too.

Comment: Sorry, included the libs as shown above, but get the error, 'function 'abs' not defined .... Using Quartus Prime Light, V20.1.1